# Is it possible for extracting object values from url link?

Tags: php

I want to extract object values instead of url parameter using PHP.
This is my link http://reussis.com/match-betting/admin2/edit_withdrawal_request.php?id=[object%20Object].

php code

```
print_r($_GET['id']);
```

When i print i didn't get any values why?
Is it foolish question please neglect. Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that, if you don't want to have a lot of params in URL then use POST method

Comment: Why GET method can't extract those values ?

Comment: You can't send objects in URL. You have to specify each object value as unique param of POST/GET method. POST method doesn't have those params in URL for safety purposes while GET method has all params in URL.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass JavaScript objects directly over HTTP, because HTTP is not JavaScript.

Serialise it by `JSON.stringify()` on your object, then pass it as an `encodeURIComponent()`'d URL string.

For example:

```
let myObject = {'javascript': 1, 'isNumberOne': true};
// Serialises the object into a string, then urlencode it
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myObject)); // "%7B%22javascript%22%3A1%2C%22isNumberOne%22%3Atrue%7D"
```

Comment: can u send any example link. Thanks!

Comment: @Rijo I've attached a short example.

Comment: How can extract 'javascript = 1' in next page using php?

Comment: If you used the above method to pass a JSON string over, in PHP use `json_decode()` to get the resulting array.

Comment: This is my current link edit_withdrawal_request.php?id={"id"%3A"7"%2C"status"%3A"0"%2C"payment_method"%3A"net banking"%2C"cust_id"%3A"1"}  I wrote this code but i can't get output $aa= json_decode($_GET['id']);
 echo $aa['id'];

Answer (score -1):

use POST method instead of GET. GET method is an old style and it is prone to the hackers. Try to reconstruct your program now! Good Luck.